# Challenges in finding critical points of a natural log function

Tags: calculus, derivatives, optimization, logarithms, maxima-minima

I have this question

> Find the critical points of $f(x) = \ln(x^3-3x+1)$.

This is a checkpoint question from my teacher and I don't understand the solution. [Question and teacher solution here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oVdjd.png).

My first question is the point $x=+1$ is not defined in the parent function but I don't understand how to take the domain of this function I am getting stuck after this.
\begin{align}
x^3-3x+1 &> 0 \\
x^3-3 &>-1
\end{align}

I don't know how to proceed further.

Then to find critical points I know you have to find the first derivative and set it to $0$ and solve for $x$. I get
$$
f'(x) = \frac{3x^2-3}{x^3-3x+1}
$$
What I am stuck with is how to set the numerator equal to $0$ and solve for $x$ I get stuck there too.

Comment: Yes you are right only $x=-1$ is the critical point. $x=1$ is not because $f(1)$ is not real.

Answer (score 1):

Your teacher is not attempting to establish what the domain of the function is - they are merely checking whether the critical values found can be input into the function to give a real answer.

As far as finding the critical values are concerned, when you solve a fraction equal to zero you only need to solve the numeratore equal to zero.